# Force close a file for copying

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

I have a web app that writes data to a file every interval, say 10 minutes.

I have another console app that reads the file and does something with data.

The problem is: sometimes the file is staled, in use by the web app while the console app is trying to copy it. Which causes error, lock error.

I have two questions, How can i force the file to closed from another program, not on the same machine?

Other question related to web app, say, there s no request coming to a server for a while, file is never closed. how can i ensure that after an interval, file is closed? background timer thread?

EDIT: OS is window 2003 server.

any suggestions?

Comment: You won't be able to get a definitive answer to your first question unless you state what operating system you're running on. So far as I know, there's no way to close a file under Windows if it's being held open by another process, except to kill the other process... but I could be wrong, and I have no clue about what may or may not work on various Unix implementations for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program "doing something with the data" doesn't actually modify the file then you can open it read-only instead and avoid the whole locking situation. Do you need write access?

You can keep track of your sessions by writing a session count function. When the number of sessions reaches zero you can then close your file. It would be helpful if you gave us more information about what exactly you are trying to do so we know the program's flow.

Use Session_Start and Session_OnEnd to keep track of sessions. This [site](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-current-users/sessions.html) has a good article on ways to keep track of sessions.